# How to retrieve Estimated Time Arrival on android?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I need to get ETA (Estimated Time Arrival) from current location of android device to another location on map. I know Google has a widget which provides ETA calculated with current traffic information. Could anybody help me with idea? I've found the JavaScript API (Google Distance Matrix API) but it is not including the traffic information and it is a JavaScript, so I hope it should be some Java API...

Comment: Is traffic information available for the city you seek? See http://maps.google.com/?ll=47.398349,-44.296875&spn=71.56992,183.339844&t=m&layer=t&z=3 and http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=61454 to confirm it is first.

Updating the original question to include the name of the city would have allowed me to answer this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately traffic does not influence the drive time provided by the Directions API.

Comment: Thanks broady! I'm confused... According to your answer and also according to some chats I assume Google stopped providing this information (ETA in traffic). But according to the link above (thewinchester: http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2549020&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=-1oqr1fsfqggj&cbrank=1) this information is provided... So is it a way to get ETA in traffic in adnroid application on Google maps?

Comment: Hi Chris. I found that Google announced that travel in traffic info is returned back:[see blog](http://www.engadget.com/2012/03/29/travel-in-traffic-estimates-return-to-google-maps-promises-not/) but I don't see any change in the directions or distance matrix. Does it mean the ETA is still not available for user applications? Do you know if Google is planning to add this feature for "directions" or "distance matrix"?

Answer (score 0):

ics has a widget that does it, but after the maps v7 update they removed the traffic app. i uninstalled the update and the widget returned.They say the update is better in every way, but I like looking at the home screen and seeing how long it will take and it will also show green for good and yellow or red for delays.